# Scanning QR codes from mirror reflections

Tags: android, qr-code

My app wants to scan QR code from its reflection from mirror. I'm using the Zxing library for that. This library is really good and works very fast. But in few devices (like Vivo, Honour) it takes lot of time to scan the QR code. Sometimes it won't even scan the QR code. I'm using the latest Zxing library 3.6.0.

Is there another suitable library?

Comment: Note that the first part of your question (how to solve the issue) is off-topic; the second one (recommending another library) is on-topic. I edited your question to remove the off-topic part.

Comment: Without details (I'm not a dev): https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/barcodescanner-lib-aar // https://github.com/dm77/barcodescann
er (those two my library scanner found in Android apps, additional to ZXing)

Answer (score 1):

If you still haven’t found a different library that meets your requirements, consider trying the [LEADTOOLS Barcode Pro Developer Toolkit](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/barcode-pro).

The toolkit supports different platforms, including Android, and it has a [free evaluation edition](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main#android) you can try before deciding whether to buy.
You can also test the barcode reading accuracy and speed on your actual devices before downloading the toolkit itself by trying the [demo app from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=leadtools.barcodedemo). If you install the app and wish to try QR performance, go to Settings -> Symbologies, de-select all types and only select QR.
Please note I work for this toolkit’s vendor.